# 128 bit hex keygen

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

So my professor gave me a challenge to build a decoder that could break his special formula. It was described to be 32 characters in length,  alphanumeric numeric when entered but then "it has a system... the first 106 bits must be 50% 1's and the rest 0's, the remaining 22 bits are basically a hash of the previous bits so that the key can be checked..." were his exact words. Sounds to me like a 128 bit encryption with a twist. I found the below but I need VB2010 or VS2010, this says php.

```
<?php
function string_random($characters, $length)
{
$string = '';
for ($max = mb_strlen($characters) - 1, $i = 0; $i < $length; ++ $i)
    {
    $string .= mb_substr($characters, mt_rand(0, $max), 1);
    }
return $string;
}

// 128 bits is 16 bytes; 2 hex digits to represent each byte
$random_128_bit_hex = string_random('0123456789abcdef', 32);
// $random_128_bit_hex might be: '4374e7bb02ae5d5bc6d0d85af78aa2ce'
```

Would that work? Or does it need converting? Please help. Oh and thank you :)
I wasn't promised extra credit but either way I would like to surprise him.

Comment: the principles will be about the same, give it a try: look up substring, random etc.  .NET has this more or less built in: `Dim myRndHex = system.Guid.NewGuid.ToString` then strip out the dashes

Comment: I dont understand the challenge - you posted a random string generator in PHP to solve a keygen issue?  What are you going to do brute force?  Also 106/22 isnt divisible by 4, so WTF.

Comment: Also clarify what you mean by hash?  A checksum?

Comment: I am sure it would be more coding but would it be possible to get the output with out the dashes? And would I need another Text box along with a converter function to get the "first 106 bits must be 50% 1's and the rest 0's, the remaining 22 bits are basically a hash of the previous bits"? Or is that what the hex string is?

Comment: Dim myRndHex = system.Guid.NewGuid.ToString.Replace("-","") Will remove the dash's - its still going to be a random string and not meet your requirements.  So, unless you clarify what you mean by hash and how 106 bits is important I cannot help.

Comment: If I were doing this I would just build an array of bytes to your requirements and convert it to ascii

Answer (score 0):

So the first 106 bit are 26 character and the first half of the 27.

You have first of all encode somehow the number of 0 and 1, while building the string you need to keep an eye to the number. An idea would be to build a map like this:

```
0 = 0000 = -4
1 = 0001 = -2
2 = 0010 = -2
3 = 0011 = 0
4 = -2
5 = 0
6 = 0
7 = +2
8 = -2
9 = 0
a = 0
b = +2
c = 0
d = +2
e = +2 
f = +4
```

then everytime you extract a new random number you check the number associated to it and add it to a variable

```
balanceOfOneAndZero
```

your objective is have balanceOfOneAndZero = 0 when you hit your 27th character.

to do that you need a control function, that takes current balanceOfOneAndZero, the proposed character proposedChar, and current string lenght currLenght.

Would be better to split the problem into two part. First is reaching the 26th character of the sequence with balanceOfOneAndZero between -2 and 2. Any other value is not acceptable, because your 27th character can have maximum two 1 or two 0 to completely balance the first 106 characters.

so your function should do something like (I'll write in sort of pseudo code since I don't have an IDE right now)

```
function checkNextLetter(Dim balanceOfOneAndZero As Integer, Dim proposedChar As Char, 
                         Dim currentLenght as Integer) As Boolean

If( ((26 - currentLenght - 1) * 4 + 2) < MOD(Map.ValueOf(proposedChar) + balanceOfOneAndZero) ) Then 
Return true
Else
Return false
ENd If


End function
```

This function basically check if accepting the new character will still make possible to Balance the number of 0 and 1 before the 26th character.
So your main function should have a loop every time it propose a new character, something like

```
proposedChar = new RandomChar
While (Not checkNextLetter(balanceOfOneAndZero, proposedChar, len(currentString))
proposedChar = new RandomChar
End While
currentString = currentString & proposedChar
```

this only until you hit the 26th character.

Than you have to check balanceOfOneAndZero, if its 2 you add a character that begin with 00, if it's 0 you can either have 10 or 01, if it's -2 you have to add a character that begin with 11.

After this I can't help you about the rest 22 character, since there are not enough information. You could brute force the rest

EDIT:

so to brute force the rest (il start from when you reach the 26th character):

Dim stringa1, stringa2, stringa3, stringa4 As String

```
If balanceOfOneAndZero = 2 Then
stringa1 = currentString & '0'
stringa2 = currentString & '1'
stringa3 = currentString & '2'
stringa4 = currentString & '3'
ELse If balanceOfOneAndZero = 0 Then
stringa1 = currentString & '4'
stringa2 = currentString & '5'
stringa3 = currentString & '6'
stringa4 = currentString & '7'
Else
stringa1 = currentString & 'c'
stringa2 = currentString & 'd'
stringa3 = currentString & 'e'
stringa4 = currentString & 'f'
End if




Function GenerateAllCombination(ByVal iLenght As Integer)

Dim arrayLista As New List(Of String)()
Dim arraySubLista As New List(Of String)()

If (iLenght > 1) Then 

arraySubLista = GenerateAllCombination(iLenght -1)

for each objString As String in arraySubLista 

    for each ele As String in arrayValori

        arrayLista.add(objString & ele)

    loop

loop


Else

    for each ele As String in arrayValori

        arrayLista.add(ele)

    loop

End If



End Function
```

Now if you use generateAllCombination you will have a List of string with ALL the combination of 5 character.
Now you just create 4 list by concatenating those combination with your string1 to string4  (string1 & combination) etc..

put all those result on a List of string, and you have 100% that at least ONE of the string will break your teacher code

I forgot, arrayValori must be a List with all values from "0" to "f"

Comment: That answer was very good considering the very poor question.  Bravo.

Comment: Thank you @Sam Makin  It's still incomplete since there are really not information about those 22 final bit (should be some sort of checksum mechanism, but it beats me that it's using so many bit) How's the syntax? It's a long time I don't use vb and without an IDE I'm lost!!

Comment: Yeah - very confusing.  I think if the user knew what they wanted we wouldn't have the question here ;)  Code looks good.  You are too nice :)

Comment: I mean, what could it be? Not a normal checksum since we know that the first 106 bit are going to be 53 1 and 53 0. We could check the number of "front", being how many time it switch between 1 and 0. but the maximum number would be again 53, and to encode it you just need 7 bit. We could also count the maximum number of consecutive 1 or 0, that would be again max 53, then another 7 bit. If we check both (but would be redundant) we would have 21 bit, which is near.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of info. Iam kind of in the dark to. But thats what makes it a challenge I suppose. Gonna put this all together shortly and see how it runs. I emailed him asking for more details and whatever it is that contains the encryption. And yes this is basicly brute force project. Thank you all so much for your help so far. Sam and seraphimFoA you guys are good at this. I hope I can learn enough to be able to help someone one day

Comment: So if it's brute force you should do the following. Build up the code that I gave you to build the first 27 character (randomly, but that will fit the rules of 50%), and then generate all the remaining combination (don't use random, just build all the combination of 5 hex character in an array, and then concat the first 27 character with each of this 5 char.)

Comment: Be aware that since you can choose between 4 different character for the 27th, you may not break the code. If you want to break the code for sure (with at least one combination) you should produce the 4 different 27 character string, and concat them with ALL the 5 character string each. This way it's 100% that one of your combination will break the code.